# A Clear, Simple, Geometry Problem

Tags: mathematics, geometry, calculation-puzzle

Draw a shape consisting of all the points equidistant from a specific point. Furthermore, draw a segment passing through a side of the shape exactly twice, and draw another segment so that it also passes through the shape exactly twice, but intersects with the other segment at one of the points where the other segment passes through the side of the shape at an angle with a measure of twenty-two plus three (add twenty-two plus three first) percent of the number of degrees around a point. Moreover, draw another segment between the points where the other two segments do not intersect each other, but intersect the first shape, and let the measure of the square of one of the other angles created by the segments be, not including the angle measure already given, the product of the fractions four-hundred sixty-eight over seventy-eight to the power of (the whole fraction is being raised to the power of another fraction, not just seventy-eight) the fraction seven thousand five hundred thirty-six over three thousand seven hundred sixty-eight, and (the second fraction in the product is as follows) one hundred sixty over sixteen to the power of (here, too the whole fraction is being raised to the power of another fraction, not just sixteen) the fraction three thousand ninety four over fifteen hundred forty-seven. If the segment that has an endpoint at the vertex of the first angle measure mentioned, and another not at the vertex of the second angle measure mentioned (but not at the vertex of the first angle, that would make a segment of length zero), has a length of the square root of the square of seven, find the area of the first shape mentioned.

Comment: Well, yes it is a geometry problem, that's why it's tagged `[geometry]`...

Comment: This [meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) relates, which does mention "an unexpected problem statement" as a reason to consider it a puzzle rather than a math problem. Not my DV just my pennyworth and I've removed my possible spoiler.

Comment: I'm on the fence as to whether this is really a puzzle in the sense current here. The actual geometry question is more or less trivial; the "real" puzzle is to wade through the deliberately opaque language in which it's stated. I'm leaning gently toward "not really a puzzle" but not firmly enough to want to mod-hammer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all the work here is in deobfuscating the wilfully unhelpful writing. It's possible that I've done it wrong, but I think this is where we end up:

That product of fractions raised to powers ends up being 3600, so the angle in question is 60 (it doesn't explicitly *say* degrees but we are clearly meant to assume this).

The shape we start with is a circle. Then we consider two chords of the circle meeting (on the circle) at right angles, with one of the angles of the triangle formed by those chords and the diameter joining the two "loose" ends being 60 degrees.

Then the "segment that has an endpoint at ..." is the one *opposite* the 60-degree angle. Its length is 7 units, so the diameter is 14/sqrt(3) units, so the radius is 7/sqrt(3) units, so the area of the circle is $\frac{49}3\pi$ units.